# Ruby: No implicit conversion of nil into Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby Rails Newbie-having issues with this code (not written by me). I feel like this should not be too hard, but when I run this, I just get 
"no implicit conversion of nil into Hash". I can not find good documentation on this. Thanks in advance!

Here is our YAML:

```
current_colleges_for_degrees:
 cahs:
   label: 'College1'
 com:
   label: 'College2 '
additional_current_colleges:
   label: 'College3'
 a&s:
   label: 'College4'
 cob:
   label: 'College5'
library:
 library1: 'Library'
```

Then our_helper file: 
(pertinent section)

```
def sorted_college_list_for_degrees
 COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["current_colleges_for_degrees"].keys.collect do |k|
  COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["current_colleges_for_degrees"][k]["label"]
 end.sort << "Other"
end


def sorted_college_list_for_degrees_with_library
 list = **(line 178)**COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["current_colleges_for_degrees"].merge(COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["library"][0])
    list.keys.collect do |k|
  [k]["label"]
end.sort << "Other"

def sorted_college_list_for_generic_works
   **(line 186)** sorted_college_list_for_degrees_with_library + COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["additional_current_colleges"]
end
```

Finally, there is the form that uses this:

```
<div class="span3">
 <%= f.input :college,
    collection: sorted_college_list_for_generic_works,
    selected: (curation_concern.college || current_user.college),
    input_html: { class: 'shrinking-form-input' },
    required: true,
    label: 'College' %>
</div>
```

This is the result from the application trace:

```
...Path/helpers/our_helper.rb:178:in `merge'
/Users/lisa/workspaces/curate/app/helpers/our_helper.rb:178:in`sorted_college_list_for_degrees_with_library'
/Users/lisa/workspaces/curate/app/helpers/our_helper.rb:186:in`sorted_college_list_for_generic_works'
```

Comment: bad naming, bed style, bad code, don't learn from it.

Comment: While these names are very descriptive, they're also super verbose and that distracts from their meaning. Are you sure the thing you're trying to add is actually defined?

Comment: @tadman No, not sure, will check.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko thanks for that, still learning... but it helps to know that!

Answer (score 2):

OK, here is your code:

```
def sorted_college_list_for_degrees_with_library
 list = **(line 178)**COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["current_colleges_for_degrees"].merge(COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["library"][0])
    list.keys.collect do |k|
  [k]["label"]
end.sort << "Other"

def sorted_college_list_for_generic_works
   **(line 186)** sorted_college_list_for_degrees_with_library + COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["additional_current_colleges"]
end
```

The error message is "no implicit conversion of nil into Hash"

This means that the Ruby method (here Merge) is expecting a hash, but you're giving it nil, and it doesn't know what to do.

Merge requires two hashes as arguments. At the end of line 187, the following bit of code looks like it may not be a hash:

```
(COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["library"][0])
```

Try inserting this:

```
puts COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["library"][0]
```

right before that line to see what the value of that bit actually is. My guess is "nil." If that value is a hash, insert this:

```
puts COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["current_colleges_for_degrees"]
```

to see if that is a hash or nil. I'm certain one or both will be nil, then you need to trace backwards and see WHY it's nil (mislabeled variable, some previous method went awry, etc)

For more details on MERGE, see [HERE](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge)

Lastly, it looks like the method "sorted_college_list_for_degrees_with_library" may be missing an "end." Perhaps this just failed to cut and paste, but take a look in the original code to see if it should be there.

Comment: Thanks, I will check into all this and come back to leave result. Thanks for the explanations - very helpful .

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the way our app is setup, I couldnt see the puts. I never could get this work.

Comment: thanks for your help... couldnt get it to work as I cant see the puts in our app. I Even tried

 `current_colleges_for_degrees:

and then removing the last item from the array with "pop" but that didnt work either
 cahs:
   label: 'College1'
 com:
   label: 'College2 '

additional_current_colleges:
   label: 'College3'
 a&s:
   label: 'College4'
 cob:
   label: 'College5'
 library: label:'library'

Comment: Look at the server logs, the puts statement is printed out there. That way you can see what the value of the thing IS, and compare that to what it SHOULD BE. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["library"]` is being used like an array, but it's defined in the YAML as a hash.

```
COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["library"]    # => { library1: 'Library' }
COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["library"][0] # => nil
```

As @CaptainChaos said, merge needs to be given a hash rather than `nil`.  Passing `nil` will cause a `no implicit conversion` error!

This could be fixed by changing the YAML to define `library` as an array with one element:

```
library:
  - label: 'Library'
```